# Switching classes from display:none to visible on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been reading a lot of past posts but I don't quite understand how to do this for my particular issue.

I have an image on the left part of my site which has two options, Cow and Pig. The way I plan on using this part of the page is as a sort of slider. I would like a user to be able to click on this image and rotate from "Cow" to "Pig" and "Pig" to "Cow" as many times as they want.

This selection dictates what background image is used in another div on the right side of the page. So upon clicking the image on the left, I would like to alternate the display properties from making the Cow visible to making the Pig visible (and toggling the display:none property from Pig to Cow).

Any help would be appreciated. I have seen http://jsfiddle.net/NjTea/5/ but it doesn't completely help me out.

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="homesplashslider">
<div class="homesplashslider2">

#slider {
float: left;

.homesplashslider {
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
background: url('../images/slider.png');
margin-top: 20px;
width: 123px;
height: 64px;

.homesplashslider2 {
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
background: url('../images/slider2.png');
margin-top: 20px;
width: 123px;
height: 64px;
    display: none;



<div id="cowandpig">
    <img class="cowtoggle" src="assets/images/cow.png">
    <img class="pigtoggle" src="assets/images/pig.png"> 
</div>

.cowtoggle {
float: right;

.pigtoggle { 
float: right;
display: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a click event on each image that hides and shows the image you need shown. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider1 = $('.homesplashslider');
  var $slider2 = $('.homesplashslider2');
  $('.cowtoggle').click(function() {
    $slider1.show();
    $slider2.hide();
  });
  $('.pigtoggle').click(function() {
    $slider2.show();
    $slider1.hide();
  });
});
```